# Sleep Interupt Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted - How to give timeout for browser for 40mins

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sleep, thread-sleep

I am trying to download an excel report from an web based application, which takes 30 mins for it to start downloading after I click 'download' button (30 mins for it to get generated and start downloading). Size of the file will be around 54 MB. Below is my code:

```
driver().findElement(By.xpath(locator_for_download)).click(); //to click on download button
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2400); //making it to sleep for 40 mins so that my report gets downloaded.
```

But, once 'download' button is clicked, after 5 mins I get below error and browser closes:

```
Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
```

I have tried to give implicit wait for 2400 seconds:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and also pageload timeout none worked.

P.S - there is no change in the URL for whatever actions we perform on it. Web application has iframes and I am doing automation in Google chrome browser.

Can anybody please help me how do i download my report as sleep is not working for me? Is it because of the browser timeout being less and is forcefully shutting down? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Are you throwing an interrupted Exception somewhere in your code to signal that a Thread should stop? A thread cant process an interrupt while it's sleeping. So you need to catch the exception when the thread comes out of sleep and then process the interrupt. may have to see some more code to give you a better idea of whats going on

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714112/wait-for-download-to-finish-in-selenium-webdriver-java

Comment: I am not throwing interrupted exception. All i have given is a sleep for 2400 seconds after i click on download button to make sure my downloading of file is complete. Here's the code :
driver().findElement(By.xpath(Control1)).click();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2400);

Comment: i also tired handling it with timeout() but i got MissingMethodException: timeout() applicable for arguement types(integer)values, below is the code
driver().findElement(By.xpath(element_locator)).click();
try
{
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2400);
}catch(Exception e)
{ 
   log.error("exception "+e.toString());
   timeout(2400*1000);
}

Comment: Get rid of the 'Thread.sleep()' and use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717512/ to wait until download is complete.

Comment: @Seema I think you are running the scripts on the node (grid/node model), if the answer is Yes. Then it explains why you are getting this exception. In your case the sleep time is > node timeout, which is causing the exception. Default timeout for the node is 300 seconds (5 minutes), meaning if the node does not receive a command within the 5 minutes then hub will automatically release the node. If you want to wait for more than 5 minutes then you have to change the either set `-timeout = 0` (to removes timeout completely) or increase it based on your scenario.

Comment: Yes, i increased the timeout setting for Node and it worked! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running the scripts on the node (grid/node model), if the answer is Yes. Then it explains why you are getting this exception.

In your case the sleep time `>` node timeout, which is causing the exception. Default timeout for the node is 300 seconds (5 minutes), meaning if the node does not receive a command within the 5 minutes then hub will automatically release the node. If you want to wait for more than 5 minutes then you have to change the either set -timeout = 0 (to removes timeout completely) or increase it based on your scenario.

Refer to [SeleniumHQ Grid documentation here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to execute the _@Tests_ on local host only.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to a [Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538249/difference-between-timeout-and-browsertimeout) is to do some action periodically on the page while waiting.
For example, code below press Tab button on `HTML` tag (or any other element) every 2 minutes for 20 minutes to prevent any timeout.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator_for_download)).click();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // Break if file downloaded before a timeout, fileDownloaded(myFileName) is example method name to check if file is downloaded.
    if (fileDownloaded(myFileName))
        break;
    
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}

if (fileDownloaded(myFileName))
    System.out.println("File downloaded successfully");
else
    System.out.println("File download failed");
```

Comment: That was a niche idea, but won't `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)` result into `ElementClickInterceptedException`?

Comment: @DebanjanB `TAB`will not

Comment: @Sers : good idea, we can keep the browser busy by having loop to use driver.getURL() function, which tries to get URL and until a specific time. Thanks for your prompt response!!